# Loop using Ruby within :javascript Haml definition

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, json, haml

I have a JSON to declare in `:javascript` and I am not familiar with Ruby. The JSON is below:

```
:javascript
  var collections = {
    feed: [{'label': 'All', 'url': 'All', 'isSelected': false}]
  };
```

But I want the part below in `feed` variable to repeat 20 times:

```
{'label': 'All', 'url': 'All', 'isSelected': true}
```

How do I do that using Ruby in Haml?

Thanks.

Comment: Would be helpful if you post some of your code around. You can always use the <% %> and the <%= %> syntax inside haml

Comment: If you just want to repeat that line as a string, you can do something like this: ``<%= 20.times { "{'label': 'All', 'url': 'All', 'isSelected': true}" } %>``. Not tested, but you should get the point

Comment: He said in haml, so there's no need of `<%=`. Just type `=`

Comment: @mischa, ups you're right, but the idea is the same ;)

Comment: I tried all above, <% %> just doesn't work in :javascript

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
:javascript
   var collections = {
     feed: [<%="{'label': 'All', 'url': 'All', 'isSelected': false}" * 20 %>]
   };
```

Another way:

```
:javascript
  var colections = {
    <%=(["feed: {'label': 'All', 'url': 'All', 'isSelected': false}"] * 20).join(',')%>
  }
```